# DELPHI Drag and Drop a Form in another form

Tags: forms, delphi, drag-and-drop

I need to drag and drop a form in another form  and then, make this dropped form child of the form it's been dragged in.

How can I do that?

Comment: What you're asking for is called *docking*.

Comment: @NewAlexandria, there not much to show for this question. It asks more for a term on which the research can even start. And the term is *"docking"* as Rob already mentioned.

Comment: Well at least we got some activity out of it

Answer (score 3):

Put a `TPanel` onto the second Form and set its `DockSite` property to True.  You can then drag&drop a Form onto that `TPanel` and it will dock inside of it as a child.

Comment: And set the form that should dock to DragKind = dkDock and DragMode = dmAutomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Remy's answer: Depending on the version of Delphi and the version of Windows you use, you won't like the builtin support. In my case, Delphi 2007 combined with Windows 8 looks terrible. Delphi 2007 with Windows XP looks ok.

You might want to have a look at the docking components in the JVCL.
* TJvDockSeverver
* TJvDockVIDStyle
* TJvDockClient

There are several examples on using them and they look much nicer even with Delphi 2007 + Windows 8 than the buildin support.